# Prove or disprove: If $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$...

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, similar-matrices

and for every $v_i$ , $i=1,..,n$ the sum of coordinates of $v_i$ is $0$, then $v_1,...,v_n$ and linearly dependent. 
What I tried to do: This questions was given after I learnt about matrix similarity and eigen vectors and eigen values, so I tried to think in that direction, I couldn't really get the question saying "the sum of coordinates of $v_i$ is $0$), because I always saw coordinates come with basis so I can use them? (would be appreciated if someone explains in what way should I understand that sentence). 
But I proceed to think in that direction and reached something: I chose matrix $A$ to be all ones, ($a_{ij}=1\space \forall i,j) $, and let $T(v)=Av$ a linear transformation, and here I got stuck but my idea was to try to say by contradiction that they're linearly  independent and reach contradiction if I find that $A$, is similiar to the zero matrix (if I use the sum of coordinates), and then explain that they can't be similar with different ranks, and prove the statement. But  I have no idea how to continue and my weak understanding of the question scares me if I'm in the right direction so I came here to ask. 
Appreciate all the help, Thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, the default basis is the standard basis.

Let $A$ be a matrix where the column vectors are $v_1,\cdots,v_n$. Then if you consider the row vector
$$
w=(\underbrace{1,\cdots,1}_{\textrm{$n$ terms}})
$$
it follows from the matrix multiplication that $wA=0$, which implies that $A$ is not of full rank and hence the column vectors are linearly dependent.

---

Notes.

If you write
$$
v_k=(a_{1k},\cdots,a_{nk})^T
$$
then the matrix $A$ is

\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&\cdots& a_{1n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&\cdots &a_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}

Note that the $k$-th column of $A$ is the vector $v_k$.

Comment: thanks!! took me a while to understand, to rephrase it and check if I understood correct, when you multiply by the ones vector, its basically getting the sum of coordinates of each column in the matrix, which is zero. it implies that $A$ is not full rank because we've found an untrivial solution to the homogeneous system, $wA=0$ (can I write it backwards like this instead of $Ax=0$?). Thanks alot again

Comment: @Pwaol: you are welcome. The reason we write $wA$ is that we use the $v_k$ as the column vectors of $A$. If you use them as the row vectors of $A$, and set $w=(1,\cdots,1)^T$, then you have $Aw=0$. You will then have the same conclusion.

Comment: @Pwaol: and your understanding is correct.

Comment: Oh yes I got that, my intention was if we can infer that it's a homogenous system solution even if it's backwards. sorry if it's a basic question, just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

There's a far simpler proof. Note that if the vectors were linearly independent, they would span $\mathbb R^n$.

I claim that $\bar 1$ is not in the span of these vectors.

To see why, note that $\bar1\cdot\bar1=n$, but $$\bar1\cdot (a_1\cdot v_1+\ldots +a_n\cdot v_n)=a_1\cdot(\bar1\cdot v_1)+\ldots+a_n\cdot(\bar1\cdot v_n)=0+\ldots+0=0$$ for any choice of coefficients $a_1,\ldots,a_n$.

Comment: I appreciate the answer! sorry if it's a basic question, but I'm not getting why if you multiplied by $1 (vector)$ you proved that it's not in the span. shouldn't it be in an equation like $a_1*v_1+...+a_n*v_n = 1 (vector) $ , for it to be in the span?

Comment: Another question about why is it equal zero, I'm sorry but I feel like I can't exactly get it, is it from the information about sum of coordinates of each vector equal zero? how can I infer that though.

Comment: The point is, if $a=b$, then $\bar1\cdot a=\bar1\cdot b$. And, $\bar1\cdot v_i$ for any $v_i$ is $0$ since $\bar1\cdot v_i$ is the sum of the components of $v_i$.

Comment: Thanks now I get the part about the zeroes, can you explain the part about how this proves that $1$ is not in the span?

Comment: Well, if $a_1\cdot v_1+\ldots+a_n\cdot v_n=\bar1$ for some choice of $a_1,...,a_n$, then $\bar1\cdot\bar1=\bar1\cdot(a_1\cdot v_1+\ldots+a_n\cdot v_n)$. But as I showed, that isn't true,

Comment: Thanks so much now it's all clear, sorry for troubling you with my questions.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**-A system of $n$ vectors $v_1,v_2,.....,v_n$ is linearly dependent if
$\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i=0$ holds for some non zero vector $(c_1,c_2,.....,c_n)$.

> In your case, indeed this non zero vector is $(1,1,.....,1)$.